# Using custom objects in a view model Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am coming from Silverlight to Knockout.js. When I would create ViewModels in Silverlight, I would often times have something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
{
  private MyCustomClass custom = null;
  public MyCustomClass Custom
  {
    get { return custom; }
    set { custom = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("MyCustomClass");
    }
  }
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Custom.PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

However, I'm not sure how to do the same kind of thing in Knockout.js. Currently, I have:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:propertyName" />

var viewModel = {
  custom: {
    propertyName:""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do what you are have there, but you would want to bind to `value: custom.propertyName` unless you have already changed context to `custom` using a template or the `with` binding in KO 1.3.

A typical way to do this is to create constructor functions for your custom object like:

```
var Person = function(first, last) {
  this.first = ko.observable(first);
  this.last = ko.observable(last);
};

var viewModel = {
  people: ko.observableArray([
     new Person("Bob", "Smith"),
     new Person("Ted", "Jones")
  ])
};
```